# Do GPCRs have 7TMHs?

Tags: proteins, cell-membrane, database

I've screened a non-redundant set of GPCRs acquired from UniProt. I found a handful of examples of record IDs that contain more than the 7 TMHs. For example [Q89609](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q89609) and [P20905](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P20905), both of which have been manually reviewed to some extent.

For an idea of the variability in the GPCR family, below is a screenshot from a Clustal Omega alignment comparing P2095 to a bonafide human GPCR. There are ~16 indels of varying length.
[image: Alignment image showing 16 indel events between the two sequences]

Also, when blasting against SwissProt, the 2 hits that appear are also GPCRs with the same function from mammals but they have the expected 7 TMHs.

[image]
Is it possible for GPCRs to contain more than 7 TMHs, or is it a case that the annotation is incorrect?

Comment: How big is the sequence homology to the GPCR that definitely have 7 tm-domains?

Comment: This is from the reference given in the SwissProt entry:  [*The predicted structure of the 5HT-dro receptor reveals... eight putative transmembrane domains instead of the expected seven*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2355663?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) I don't have journal access right now, but the paper may be insightful.

Comment: @Chris I've compared one to a bona fide GPCR, however, the sequence variation in the GPCR family makes this a tricky question to answer. [Also, sequence homology is rife with errors when examining TM proteins](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1000867).

Comment: @canadianer Thanks for this. Evidently, my question is long standing from the 1990s! Originally I suspected SignalP had made an error and the first TMH would be cleaved, but that paper suggests it's the second TMH that is not found in other GPCRs. I'll give this a thorough read.